# Architectur and software selection improvement

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Im working on a script to autoinstall some software for different departments. This is how it currently looks like:

[image: Script Gui Example]

The Idea is to have a dropdownlist where you can choose a specific department.
After you choose for example "Marketing" the programm should automark the Chechboxes for the x86 or x64 architecture and the Programms they need to be installed for this department. (So I would like to build a template what Powershell can call after choosing the department.

So far I build the "Architectur-chooser"

```
$wmiquery = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor | Select-Object AddressWidth)

$wmiquery = $wmiquery.AddressWidth

[string]$wmiquery2 = $wmiquery

write-host $wmiquery2
```

Powershell is asking for the architecture and gives out the 32 or 64 as a string. In a previus script is used it like this.

```
switch ($wmiquery2) {
     "64" {
        x64
        x86_x64
     }
     "32" {
        x86
        x86_x64
     }


function x64 {
    Copy-Item -Path "#" -Destination "#"  

    Start-Process "#" /qn -Wait

    Remove-Item -Path "#"
}

function x32 {
    Copy-Item -Path "#" -Destination "#"  

    Start-Process "#" /qn -Wait

    Remove-Item -Path "#"
}
```

But I guess this wont work this time :/

I also build a test part of the GUI with a example pick.

```
###Windowloader
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('mscorlib')
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

### Height and width of window
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.width = 400
$objForm.height = 900
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

### Set the font of the text to be used within the form
    $objFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",09)
    $objForm.Font = $Font


### set objform icon
$objform.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("#")


### set objform text
$objForm.Text = "Installmanager"



###Drowdown position, height, list
$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Treffen Sie bitte eine Auswahl:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objCombobox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox 
$objCombobox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objCombobox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 

[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("IT")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Controlling")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Redaktion")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Disposition")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Grafik")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Redaktion(Schnitt)")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Sekreteriat")

$objCombobox.Height = 70
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCombobox) 
$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})

$x
### Checkboxdescrption
        ###Textbox 32 Bit
        $obj32Bit = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $obj32Bit.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,100) 
        $obj32Bit.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,20) 
        $obj32Bit.Text = "32 Bit"
        $obj32Bit.Name = "32 Bit"
        $objForm.Controls.Add($obj32Bit)

        ###Textbox 64 Bit
        $obj64Bit = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $obj64Bit.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,100) 
        $obj64Bit.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,20) 
        $obj64Bit.Text = "64 Bit"
        $obj64Bit.Name = "64 Bit"
        $objForm.Controls.Add($obj64Bit)

        ###Textbox application
        $objProgrammText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $objProgrammText.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,100) 
        $objProgrammText.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,20) 
        $objProgrammText.Text = "Anwendung"
        $objProgrammText.Name = "Programm"
        $objForm.Controls.Add($objProgrammText)


        ### 7zip
        $obj7zipText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $obj7zipText.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,128) 
        $obj7zipText.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20) 
        $obj7zipText.Text = "7Zip"
        $obj7zipText.Name = "7Zip"
        $objForm.Controls.Add($obj7zipText)


        ###Java
        $objJava = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
        $objJava.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(20,145)
        $objJava.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(40,50)
        $objJava.Checked = $false
        $objForm.Controls.Add($objJava)  



    ###Checkbox Programm 32 Bit
    $obj7zip = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $obj7zip.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(20,110)
    $obj7zip.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(40,50)
    $obj7zip.Checked = $false
    $objForm.Controls.Add($obj7zip) **


    ###Checkbox Programm 64 Bit
    $obj7zip64 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $obj7zip64.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,110)
    $obj7zip64.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(40,50)
    $obj7zip64.Checked = $false
    $objForm.Controls.Add($obj7zip64)

    ###Java
    $objJava = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $objJava.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,145)
    $objJava.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(40,50)
    $objJava.Checked = $false
    $objForm.Controls.Add($objJava)  


### OK Button End
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,700)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Name = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton) 



### OK Button Top
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(290, 40)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80, 23)
$Button.Text = "OK"
$Button.add_Click(
{
    $obj7zip64.Checked = $false
    $obj7zip32.Checked = $false
    $dropdown = $objCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString()
    if ($dropdown -eq "Controlling") {
        $obj7zip64.Checked = $true
    #if ($dropdown -eq "Sekretariat") {
        #$obj7zip64.Checked = $false

#}
}
}
)


$objForm.Controls.Add($Button)


###Shows Window
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

At the last Button (### OK Button Top) I wrote a example and this works so far. But if you build this way for 20-30 different softwares I will get such a huge and confused list.

So maybe you have an Idea for me how to manage this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Environment variable `$env:ProgramW6432` for the installation so you don't have to determine the architecture at all and only need a single checkbox for each program.

For your software list I would create an array and create the GUI dynamically:

```
# ....

[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("IT")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Controlling")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Redaktion")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Disposition")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Grafik")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Redaktion(Schnitt)")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Sekreteriat")

$objCombobox.Height = 70
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCombobox) 
$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})


$programList = @(
    '7-Zip'
    'Java'
    'Outlook'
    'SqlServer'
    'Visual Studio'
    'Skype for Business'
    'Notepad++'
    'Chrome'
    'IIS'
)

### Checkboxdescrption
###Textbox 32 Bit
$obj32Bit = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$obj32Bit.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,100) 
$obj32Bit.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,20) 
$obj32Bit.Text = "32 Bit"
$obj32Bit.Name = "32 Bit"
$objForm.Controls.Add($obj32Bit)

###Textbox 64 Bit
$obj64Bit = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$obj64Bit.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,100) 
$obj64Bit.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,20) 
$obj64Bit.Text = "64 Bit"
$obj64Bit.Name = "64 Bit"
$objForm.Controls.Add($obj64Bit)

###Textbox application
$objProgrammText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objProgrammText.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,100) 
$objProgrammText.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,20) 
$objProgrammText.Text = "Anwendung"
$objProgrammText.Name = "Programm"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objProgrammText)


$height = 128
$programList | ForEach-Object {

    $currentObj = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $currentObj.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, $height) 
    $currentObj.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20) 
    $currentObj.Text = $_
    $currentObj.Name = $_
    $objForm.Controls.Add($currentObj)


    ###Checkbox Programm 32 Bit
    $currentObj32  = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $currentObj32.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(20,($height -18))
    $currentObj32.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(40,50)

    $currentObj32.Checked = $false
    $objForm.Controls.Add($currentObj32) 


    ###Checkbox Programm 64 Bit
    $currentObj64 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $currentObj64.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,($height -18))
    $currentObj64.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(40,50)
    $currentObj64.Checked = $false
    $objForm.Controls.Add($currentObj64)

    $height += 33

}



    ### OK Button End
    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,700)
    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.Name = "OK"
    $OKButton.DialogResult = "OK"
    $OKButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
    $objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton) 

#....
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i need to have both checkboxes that you can choose manually 32bit for Systems with lower Hardware for example.

Comment: I figured out a problem for me with your great Dynamic method. In my version I used "$obj7zip.Checked = $false/true" to chang the status in the GUI. Now with the Dynamic method I dont have this option anymore. My thought was, that i may can count out the "ForEach-Object" and work with the numbers it gives me out. But this seems to complicated for me as a solution. Do you have any Idea how I get the stats back to Manipulate the Checkboxes to true or false?